# tirando as virgulas e ordenando com php mysql

Tags: array

Tenho um problema aqui pra resolver...
Pego no banco os numeros que estão agrupados com virgula.
Separo com explode
Ex:

```
$dados = "36,38,40,42";

$separar = explode(",",$dados);
$result = $separar[0];
```

Agora entra a dúvida... como listar esses dados numa while?
Esses dados farão parte de inputs. Exemplo:

```
<ul>
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($prod)){
$dados = $array['$dados'];
echo "
<li><input name='dados' type='radio' value='$dados'><label>$dados</label></li>";
}
</ul>";
```

Comment: Mas esses números são para colocar em etiquetas `<input>` ou são id's de algo que você tem que ir ao banco buscar ?

Answer (score 1):

Se vc já usou o explode, então $separar já é um array, então é mais prático vc percorrer o array usando o foreach invés do while.

```
foreach($separar as $item){
/*Aqui, você pode criar seus inputs, a variável item vai ter o valor do item atual*/
}
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Nunca foi tão fácil e prático!! Obrigado à todos!!

Answer (score 0):

Se for vários registros cada um com vários números separados por virgula você faz assim:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db');

$array = array();

if($th = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `suatabela` WHERE 'sua condição for verdadeira'"){
    while($row = $th->fetch_assoc()){
        //Faço a separação do registro atual
        $v = explode(",", $row['campo']);
        $i = 0

        while($i < count($v)){
            //Então o add no array
            array_push($array, $v[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
   }
}


//Então faço o que quero
$i = 0
while ($i < count($array)) {
    echo $array[$i];
    $i++;
}
```